# How do I pass a system property to Maven test in intelliJ IDE

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have a Junit test that I need to pass a system property to make the test pass. I can accomplish this using the command line like this:

> mvn test -Dvin_patterns_dir=/Users/myUser/myResourceDir

And this works great, except I want to accomplish the same thing in IntelliJ IDEA. I looked into various settings in IntelliJ for Maven but not finding any.

I am using:

- Java 1.8.0_66
- Maven 3.3.9
- IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4 Community edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using surefire, you can simply pass system properties in your pom,  See http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html for an example.  Then, in IntelliJ, simply run your project's test phase.

Comment: Thanks Michael,I am looking at the link you sent, is the <propertyName>propertyValue</propertyName> be like <vin_patterns_dir>/Users/myUser/myResourceDir</vin_patterns_dir >  or is it  <propertyName>vin_patterns_dir</propertyName> and then how do set the value of this property?  do you have an example handy?

Comment: ok, that worked, I used the form <vin_patterns_dir>/Users/myUser/myResourceDir</vin_patterns_dir>

Comment: Yeah good question and answer its a lot confusing with this syntax to identify where exactly the property name and value goes

Answer (score 1):

For others looking for this later, if the system property really is what you want, rather than modifying your pom (which applies to all systems), you can do this by creating a configuration, and modifying the command line parameters.

Within the configuration, go to Runner and add VM Options.